# Can we say that a mutation is "one or more events that changes a state in a particular way"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, state, mutation

As I understand, a state is a certain situation of a program (say, 1 product in the shopping car).

An event (a change of state) in which `let sumOfProducts = 0` becomes 1.

Yet, I'm not sure I understand why this terminology isn't enough and the "mutation" and "mutation observer" terms are needed as well to describe state changes.

---

### My question

Can we say that a mutation is:

> **one or more** events that changes a state in a particular way?

In other words, is mutation just a fancy way to describe a series of events, like "from 0 `sumOfProducts = 0` to 1, but with the price of 1000$ (2 events total).

Answer (score 0):

When mentioning `mutation` or Immutability  in the context of state management, we often refer to the way you change the object.
Primitive data types such as `string`, `number`, `boolean`, `null`, `undefined`, `symbol` (new in ECMAScript 2015). are immutable by default.

`Object` and `Array` are reference type and they are mutable.
mutating an `object` or an `Array` is [considered a bad practice or an anti pattern is some state manager libraries](https://reactjs.org/docs/update.html) such as `redux`.

Comment: The downvote (which I chose to counteract) may have been because people who think a question should not have been asked on SO in the first place sometimes want to _punish_ anyone who writes an answer, independent of the merit of that answer. I'm not sure if your answer fully responds to the more ReactJS specific part _"why...the "mutation" and "mutation observer" terms are needed"_ I think the question is a bit unclear, is it about mutation in general or about an aspect of ReactJS?

Comment: ok fair enough, as i understand the question, the OP is asking if a mutation is a series of changes to a value (object). and in my opinion it could be true, well at least not totally wrong. but when you talk about mutation in a certain context like javascript or react, mutation is often mentioned as for state managers. i do think react has an opinion on this thats why i shared [this link from the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/update.html#the-main-idea)